# run into OutOfMemoryException after dbQuery

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, yield-return

I´m running a DB-query which returns a quite big amount of features (some 100000). Because I run into the mentioned exception I tried to split the query into several subqueries. But hence the result of all these subqueries however is written to the methods list and therefor to memory I still run into the same exception.

So I wondered if I may use `yield return` after every subquery has finished by looping its elements and returning every single one.

After the features have been retrieved I have to create some new custom objects for every single of them, so I wondered if using yield return would be memory-saving in this case.

Maybe the following makes it a bit clearer:

```
foreach (var chunk in IDs.chunk(500))
{       
    List<ComplexObject> result = new List<ComplexObject>():

    // ...
    // make a (sub-)query on every chunk to retrieve 500 objects at once
    // ..

    // now we have up to 500 ComplexObjects within result
    foreach (var parcel in result)
    {
        yield return parcel;
        parcel.Release();       // release COM-object
    }
}
```

Where `chunk` is a (sub)-collection of 500 elements (IDs).

Afterwards I loop the results retrieved from that method within `foreach` and create the custom objects from them.

EDIT: I could also query and handle every `ComplexObject` one by one, in fact this is much slower then retrieving a bunch of let´s say 500 elements because MetaData has only to be retrieved once rather then for every single object (there are more reasons but this one is most convenient).

Comment: These are COM objects, but the data is retrieved from a database? Does the caller of this method need to have all of them at once, or can the caller process items one by one? Why do you retrieve 500 objects "at once"?

Comment: Yeap, the caller may use them one by one rather then all at once. While making the query I have a method that accepts a collection of IDs and retrieves all its corresponding `ComplexObjects` in an Array, so actually the `result` would be an array rather then a list, but I suppose that´ll make no difference.

Comment: But how does the db query part look like? That's the actual place which needs to be changed (the result of that method needs to be an `IEnumerable<ComplexObject>`).

Comment: The actual query is within a blackbox (at least to me) and does return an array. But hence 500 elements is a small collection I wanted to collect 500 elements at once (with the mentioned query) and afterwards loop every single of them and directly send it to the caller rather than waiting until all chunks have been handled.

Comment: "Small collection" is a relative term. If each of these objects consumes 2MB of memory, you are talking about 1GB of RAM. What does "blackbox (at least to me)" mean? Do you have the code which you can modify or not? Can you set the chunk size to 1? Because that would effectively turn this into a "create-process-release" action for each instance.

Comment: see my edit why I handle chunks rather then single objects

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using to create these objects? I am not sure which metadata you're talking about.

Comment: Well, its a mixture of some 3rd-party library (ESRI ArcGIS) and some thousdands of lines of our company (for just retrieve the objects). This also includes retrieve for MetaData (which is much more then simply getting every attributes datatype, its about getting the exact table, timestamps for historic versions of the feature, sub-tables...), may we chat?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid storing the results in a list altogether. The main idea is to instantiate each expensive object, process it, and then dispose it immediately.

That means your outer method would look something like:

```
foreach (var chunk in IDs.SplitIntoChunks(size: 500))
{
    foreach (var parcel in EnumerateComplexObjects(chunk))
    {
        yield return parcel;
    }
}
```

And the `EnumerableComplexObjects` would also use `yield return`:

```
IEnumerable<ComplexObject> EnumerateObjects(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        using (var obj = CreateSingleComplexObject(id))
        {
            yield return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, once you do this, you don't even need chunks anymore:

```
foreach (var obj in EnumerateObjects(allIDs)
{
     Process(obj);
}
```